# Using default methods as a base for properties of beans declared in XML?

Tags: java, spring

I have default methods, such as `setXxx(X x)` and `X getXxx()`, but spring won't recoginze those as properties. Is it possible to somehow avoid method duplication if I want to use this interface in different classes?

Example:

```
public class Type {... }

public interface TypeSupport {
    Type getType();
    default String getTypeName(){ 
        return getType().getName(); 
    }
    default void setTypeName(String name){
        getType().setName(name);
    }
}

public class TypedVariable implements TypeSupport {
    private Type type = new Type();
    @Override public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

I want to define `TypedVariable` bean in xml configuration:

```
<bean id="typedVariable" class="com.example.TypedVariable">
    <property name="typeName" value="string"/>
</bean>
```

When running, Spring fails with an error indicating that `TypedVariable` has no writeable property `typeName`.

Comment: Spring is actually uses java bean utilities to lookup for properties. The same question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219006/default-method-in-interface-in-java-8-and-bean-info-introspector